# Why does c++ ifstream read the file with duplicate records

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading from text file until EOF repeats last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line)
>   [c++ EOF running one too many times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236006/c-eof-running-one-too-many-times)

I am writing a simple c++ code to read and write a binary file but I found that the ifstream will read the record twice. I don't know how this happens but I try to compile the code with mingw32 in windows and linux, the same case

```
ofstream outfile;
int data[5];
outfile.open("abc.out", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
data[0] = data[1] = 1;
data[2] = data[3] = 2;
data[4] = -1;
cout << "ORIGINAL DATA:" << data[0] << " " << data[1] << " "  << data[2] << " "  << data[3] << " "  << data[4] << endl << endl;
outfile.write((char *)&data[0], 5*sizeof(int));
outfile.close();    


ifstream infile;
infile.open("abc.out", ios::in | ios::binary);
data[0] = data[1] = data[2] = data[3] = data[4] = 0;
while (!infile.eof())
{
  infile.read((char *)&data[0], 5*sizeof(int));
  cout << data[0] << " " << data[1] << " "  << data[2] << " "  << data[3] << " "  << data[4] << endl;
}
```

Here is the output

ORIGINAL DATA:1 1 2 2 -1

1 1 2 2 -1

1 1 2 2 -1

Comment: `infile.eof()` returns true only *after* failing to read, so the loop runs one time too much.

Comment: Thank Bo Persson, but I still don't understand how to fix that. Reading "Reading from text file until EOF repeats last line", I try the following code 

    while (true) {
    ...
    if( infile.eof() ) break;
    }

but still doesn't work

Comment: @user - You can test for eof, or check the return value of `read` (hint, hint!), before deciding to write to cout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever use `.eof()` or `.good()` as  loop condition. It almost always produces buggy code (as it does in this case).

The idiomatic pattern for reading data is C++ is this:

```
while (infile.read((char *)&data[0], 5*sizeof(int)))
{  
  cout << data[0] << " " << data[1] << " "  << data[2] << " "  
       << data[3] << " "  << data[4] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @BoPersson already pointed out, the problem stems from using `while (!infile.eof())`, which is *virtually* always an error. Instead, you want to check the result of reading the data. A first approximation would look something like this:

```
// prefer 1-step initialization -- supply parameters to ctor.
ifstream infile("abc.out", ios::in | ios::binary); 

while (infile.read((char *)&data[0], 5*sizeof(int))
    cout << data[0] << " " 
         << data[1] << " "  
         << data[2] << " "  
         << data[3] << " "  
         << data[4] << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Jerry Coffin. It works :)

Answer (score 1):

Since a stream goes *bad* when a read fails and a *bad* stream can be seen as a false bool, and since read returns the stream istelf,
you can do

```
while(infile.read((char *)&data[0], 5*sizeof(int)))
  cout << data[0] << " " << data[1] << " "  << data[2] << " "  << data[3] << " "  << data[4] << endl;
```

thus leaving the loop just on the read failure.